# dynamically get options of a dropdown menu in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

The main problem is that I have a dropdown menu whose options should be updated dynamically.
The workflow is as follows:
I have an `input` element connected to an `ng-model` called `toSubmit` that when longer than 3 characters should fire an `http.get` call to fetch the list that should populate the dropdown menu.
So this list will change everytime the `toSubmit` variable changes. Let's call this list `database` (in the controller it is `$scope.database`.

What I am trying right now is a very simple solution that doesn't work most probably because the html DOM that contains the dropdown list is loaded at the very beginning and does not keep track of the changes in the options.

In my controller I have the following part which watches over `toSubmit`:

```
$scope.toSubmit = '';

$scope.$watch('toSubmit',function(query){


          if (query.length >= 3){

            getQueryDatabases.companyNameService({'field':'name','query':query,'numberOfHits':'10'},'CIK').prom.then(
            function(dataObject){

                  $scope.database = dataObject;

                  // dataObject.forEach(function(item){
                  //   $scope.databaseString.push(item.cik + ' ' + item.companyName);
                  });

                });

          }
        });
```

And my html looks like the following:

```
<label for="nameCompany">Name:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="toSubmit"></input>
<select ng-model="database" ng-options="line in database"></select>
```

Now my take was take by binding `database` with `ng-Model` I would get the result but I am most likely wrong. Can someone please help me?

Comment: That is confusing, because your choice in the dropdown will overwrite the list. Probably shouldn't have ng-model and ng-options pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) that'll handle things like limiting input before server request and have great look and extendibility.

You need to add [angular-ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) to your project. 
Here is code for you:
Html:

```
<input class='form-control' data-ng-model='position.company' data-ng-required data-placeholder='Company:' data-ui-select2='employerSelect2Options' id='company_name' type='hidden'>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $scope.employerSelect2Options = {
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    query: function (query) {
        var _query = query;
        var companies = Restangular.all('companies').getList({query: query.term});

        companies.then(function(data) {
            var results = {results: []};
            _.each(data, function(element, index, list) {
                results.results.push({id: element.id, text: element.name});
            })
            if(!_.contains(_.map(data, function(element){ return element.name; }), _query.term)) {
                results.results.push({id: _query.term , text: 'Create company "' + _query.term + '"'});
            }
            _query.callback(results);
        })
    }
};
```

My example also contains logic for add "create company" if zero results returned. In this case position.company will contain text of non found company name in id field and you can check it on server side and create one before assigning id. 
This logic in

```
if(!_.contains
```

condition.